# Insert only 10 elements to an array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a struct named `Thing`:

```
struct Thing {
  var name: String
  var description: String
}
```

and an array `things = [Thing]()` that contains 100 elements.

Now I want something like `elements.addObjectsFromArray(things.subarrayWithRange(NSMakeRange(0, 10)))` to populate my `tableView`, but

> [Thing] has no member addObjectsFromArray.

I know `elements.insertContentsOf(things, at: 0)`, but it inserts all elements of `things`.

How can I insert only 10 elements in needed range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the range subscript to get a slice of an array and then append:

```
// create the mutable array
var elements = [0]

// create the big array
let bigArray = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 

// take a slice of bigArray from index 5 up to but 
// not including index 10 and append it to the mutable array
elements += bigArray[5..<10]

// elements is [0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop!

Don't get me wrong! I mean a C-style for loop, not a `for-in` loop. The former is useful when you want to repeat something for a number of times.

We will first loop through the `things`, but only for the first 10 items! Then we stop.

```
for var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
    elements.append(things[i])
}
```

See? That's very straightforward, isn't it?

I know that Jack Lawrence already posted another answer, but this is an alternative approach. See if you like it or not!

Comment: FWIW this is less efficient and uses a feature (C-style for loop) that isn't going to be available in Swift 3.

Comment: What? C-style for loop are not available in Swift 3? That's so sad! I love using them!

Comment: @Sweeper Indeed, the feature is being removed. The closest you will be able to get is `for i in 0..<10 { }`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the CollectionType function

```
struct Thing {
    var name: String
    var description: String
}

let things:[Thing] = Array(count: 20, repeatedValue: Thing(name: "TestName",     description: "TestDescription"))
var elements:[Thing] = []
//subArray from 0 to 9
let subThings = things.prefix(10)
elements.appendContentsOf(subThings)
```